# Cocoapods will not install?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Analytics`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I have added pods painlessly to many projects in the past, but now, no new pods will install. I ran pod repo update, I updated my Cocoapods version, turned use_frameworks! on and off, and I am out of ideas.

here is the Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'My App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  #use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for My App
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxAlamofire'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  source 'https://github.com/lixiang1994/Specs'
  pod 'Loading'

end
```

Comment: Is this the first project you have added a `source` to?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: have you tried `pod install --repo-update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of your file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Cocoapods will add that source by default if no other source is present. By adding your own source Cocoapods assumes everything can be found there.

Comment: With recent CocoaPods versions, `source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` is much faster than `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

Comment: how long does source `'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` usually take

Comment: I've never had to wait very long using that source and it isn't like you install pods all that often. I had no idea they added a new source but seems like either will work. You could always try each source and see if you notice a difference.